# Angularjs + Flask-wtf: Bad request 400

Tags: ajax, angularjs, flask, flask-wtforms, bad-request

I got a very strange issue with wtf-forms where I send a request using the angularjs $http-module. Upon initializing the WTForm I recieve a **Bad request: 400** error. For testing purposes I disabled csrf protection. I have seriously no idea where to look for the problem. The following is the minimal failing:

Angularjs service sending the request:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('surname', _gifter.surname);
data.append('lastname', _gifter.lastname);
data.append('email', _gifter.email);
data.append('email_confirm', _gifter.email_confirm);
data.append('prize', gift.prize);

$http.post('ajax/claim/' + DataProvider.gift.id + '/', data)
```

Flask route:

```
@app.route('/ajax/claim/<int:gift_id>/', methods = ['POST'])
def claim_gift(gift_id):
    print("request:" + request.data)
    claim_form = ClaimGiftForm(csrf_enabled=False)
    return 'success'
```

WTForm:

```
class ClaimGiftForm(Form):
    surname = TextField(
        validators=[validators.Required()])
    lastname = TextField(
        validators=[validators.Required()])
    email = EmailField(
        validators = [
            validators.email(),
            validators.Required()])
    email_confirm = EmailField(
        validators = [
            validators.Required(),
            validators.EqualTo()])
    prize = IntegerField()
```

When I print the request (see in 'Flask route') the data seems to be ok - everything is transmitted correctly. But upon initializing the form I get the aforementioned error.

**Edit1:** I just found out, that for some reason the `request.form` MultiDict is empty, allthough `request.data` contains the expected data. However I have no idea why this is the case.

**Edit2:**
`pprint(request.data)` gives:

```
-----------------------------109386632915471364402090498247\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="surname"\r\n\r\ntheName\r\n
-----------------------------109386632915471364402090498247\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="lastname"\r\n\r\ntheLastname\r\n
-----------------------------109386632915471364402090498247\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="email"\r\n\r\nsomeone@somewhere.net\r\n
-----------------------------109386632915471364402090498247\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="email_confirm"\r\n\r\nsomeone@somewhere.net\r\n
-----------------------------109386632915471364402090498247\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="prize"\r\n\r\n12\r\n
-----------------------------109386632915471364402090498247--\r\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript has `email_confirmed` but the form's field is `email_confirm`.

Comment: I just facepalmed so hard. I'll see tomorrow if this fixes it.

Comment: Okay unfortunately this was just a typo in the question. I edited it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

It was the header of the ajax request. I needed to add a header-config object:

```
{
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
    transformRequest: angular.identity
}
```

The whole request now looks like this:

```
$http.post('ajax/claim/' + DataProvider.gifts[index].id + '/', data, {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
    transformRequest: angular.identity
).success(...);
```

I consider this question as closed.